# What is the difference between f:link and f:uri ViewHelpers in TYPO3 fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

There are a number of viewhelpers which can be used in Fluid. The [f:link](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Link/Index.html) and [f:uri](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Uri/Index.html) seem to do basically the same thing.

For example:

- [f:link.external](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Link/External.html) :
  *"A ViewHelper for creating links to external targets."*
- [f.uri.external](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Uri/External.html) : 
  *"This ViewHelper creates a link to an external page"*

This results in the following questions:

1. What's the difference between f.link.external and f.uri.external (and which is supported in which Fuid / TYPO3 version?).
2. For which TYPO3 version is the documentation "[Extbase Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide)"? Because usually you see a version in lower left column, here it just shows 'latest'.
3. What is the best up-to-date resource for Fluid ViewHelpers using TYPO3 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All `link` viewhelpers in Fluid render a full HTML link, so `<a href="..." ...>...</a>`. In comparison all `uri` viewhelpers only render the URI, thus what would end up within `href` of a link or e.g. a `src()` in CSS.
2. The Extbase guide is rarely updated and there is no real version dependency. If at all it applies to the latest LTS but you'll find outdated info here and there.
3. There are some docs around the net which cover parts of Fluid but there is no definite guide which contains everything. Here are a few resources:

   - [Viewhelpers reference in Fluid powered TYPO3](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers.html)
   - [Viewhelpers in the Fluid Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Index.html)
   - [Source code of TYPO3 Fluid](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid)
   - [Source code of TYPO3](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/tree/TYPO3_8-7)

You are very welcome to improve the docs wherever you see something amiss. :-)

Comment: Please also keep in mind that Fluid is an external project that is used within TYPO3. Fluid itself comes with a set of ViewHelpers (TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers) but the ViewHelpers you use here are TYPO3 ViewHelpers (TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers).

Answer (score 2):

`f.link.external` actually creates a **link** and `f.uri` just outputs the **uri**.

---

### f.link.external

Fluid Source:

```xml
<f:link.external  uri="https://typo3.org">f.link.external</f:link.external>
```

Result:

```xml
<a href="https://typo3.org">f.link.external</a>
```

### f.uri.external

Fluid Source:

```xml
<f:uri.external  uri="https://typo3.org">f.uri.external</f:uri.external>
```

Result:

```xml
https://typo3.org
```

It might be a good idea to update the documentation for [f.uri.external](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Uri/External.html) because it is misleading.